# ACI caching docker images after pull

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

Primarily I have a docker container with MSBuild tools installed and the Vsts agent. Building the docker container takes a fair amount of time because of the visual studio installer. (45 minutes on local machine)

In Azure DevOps I've created a pipeline that uses this image to start, build and deploy our applications. After finishing the build it should stop the container till next request.

I thought that using ACI would make my current local build server obsolete, because i find it a little bit stupid to have a full blown windows server to run docker on it with the containers also running a full blown windows server. 
Either i missed something or running msbuild and the agent on the physical server defeats the purpose of the whole docker solution.

On the other side, removing this physical server and replace it by ACI should do the trick. Starting and stopping this container with Azure Cli can be handled by Azure Devops. The only issue here is that the container instance is stateless, which has a nasty side effect of pulling the image every time the instance is started which takes an half hour to complete. Keep the instance running is a no-go because of the costs.
If only the pulled image is cached and used on every restart, this would be the ultimate solution but sadly it's not.

Did i missed something in the preliminary investigation or did i made some wrong assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can have cache in Azure Devops, it has some of the base images cached already, you can query [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/listcachedimages/listcachedimages) to find them out.

> Azure Container Instances uses a caching mechanism to help speed
>   container startup time for images built on common Windows base images,
>   including nanoserver:1809, servercore:ltsc2019, and servercore:1809.
>   Commonly used Linux images such as ubuntu:1604 and alpine:3.6 are also
>   cached.

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#what-windows-base-os-images-are-supported
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting?view=azurermps-6.13.0#cached-images

Comment: Thank you, i have already noticed this. I'm looking for another solution to remove my  physical server i have on premise.

Comment: create a vm in Azure and use that as an Agent ;)

Comment: Ok that is for now the only reasonable solution. Thank you.

Comment: you use your kubernetes cluster with windows nodes to host your agent (that would have cache), but that is if you have one ;)

Comment: I saw that suggestion before, but i didn't find info about how to set something like that up. Especially the starting up and shutting down of a single agent i could not find. Is it not overkill to set up a kubernetes cluster for one agent? Maybe i should move my app services also to containers to avoid extra costs?

Comment: that is certainly a possibility (moving app services to kubernetes). I'd say its definitely an overkill to create a kubernetes cluster for one agent.

Comment: If I use a cached base image, and build my layers ontop of it. When pulling from ACR will it speed things up if the base is cached?